# javascript function is supposed to display php SESSION data but isn't called

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a regular old registration form for a website; and I'm trying to display the name of the logged-in user(if any) at the top of the page. However, the function that is supposed to update that field doesn't seem o be called at all, and I can't make heads or tails of it, nor of the error messages my console displays:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < -- pagina_registrazione.php:36"
"Uncaught ReferenceError: update_name is not defined 
     onload                               -- pagina_registrazione.php:10"

here is the code:

```
<?php
    require './config_db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  lang = "it" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name = "keywords" content = "catcher, profilo, registrazione, utente">
        <meta name="author" content="Luca Ballarati">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../stile/sottopagine.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <title>pagina di registrazione</title>
    </head>
    <body onload=update_name>
        <section>
            <p id="spia_connessione">NOMEUTENTEQUI</p>
            <p>Se hai già un'account <a href = "./pagina_login.php"><strong>clicca qui</strong></a> per accedere.</p>
            <p>Altrimenti <strong>registrati</strong> compilando i campi qui sotto</p>
        </section>
        <div id="login_form">
            <form name="registra" action="./pagina_registrazione.php" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label><p>Nome Utente</p></label>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="nome_utente" name="username" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><p>Password</p></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><p>Conferma Password</p></label>
                   <input type="password" placeholder="conferma_password" name="passwordconfirm" required>
                </div>
                <input name="pulsante_invio" type="submit" value="Invia">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['pulsante_invio'])) {
                        $nomeutente = $_POST['username'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $cpassword = $_POST['passwordconfirm'];
                        if ($password==$cpassword) {
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE NomeUtente='$nomeutente'";
                            $esegui_query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($esegui_query)>0) {
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                window.alert("Nome Utente già usato: registrarsi con un diverso Nome Utente");
                                </script>';
                            }
                            else {
                                $query = "INSERT INTO utenti (NomeUtente,Password,Record,Partite)
                                    VALUES('$nomeutente','$password',0,0)";
                                $esegui_query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                if ($esegui_query) {
                                    $nome = $_SESSION['username'];
                                    //porta l'utente alla pagina di login
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        window.alert("Utente registrato correttamente");
                                    </script>';
                                    //echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        //document.getElementById("spia_connessione").innerHTML = "'$nome'";
                                    //</script>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        window.alert("Errore durante la registrazione");
                                        </script>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                window.alert("Password e Password di conferma devono essere uguali");
                            </script>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
             </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update_name() {
                window.alert("nome utente aggiornato");
                var nm = <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>;
                document.getElementById("spia_connessione").innerHTML = nm;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you look at the generated html? One possible problem is that you need quotes around the username: `var nm = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>';`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Use "view source" directly on the generated page and check your Javascript at the bottom of the page to see where your JS error comes from.

Comment: You can make it character safe by using json_encode (even though its just a string, it works): `var nm = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['username']); ?>;` ... do NOT wrap the php in quotes if you use json_encode, as json_encode includes quoting of the string itself. Also, with js errors, always look at the raw source of the html output by php.

Comment: It turned out the problem was I couldn't call a php variable from within javascript code if it was used as a string in an echo statement. I solved the problem by separating the php code and the javascript code like this:

Comment: <?php
                $nome;
                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {$nome =$_SESSION['username'];}
                else {$nome = "nessun utente connesso";}
                if (!$nome || $nome == "") {$nome = "non definito";}
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("spia_connessione").innerHTML = '<?php echo $nome; ?>';
            </script>

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code on the top of your php file.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: doing only that, nothing changed.

Comment: However, I also chenged a couple things on my own, while also adding the code you wrote. now I only get the error: "Uncaught Syntax error: unexpected indentifier -- pagina_registrazione.php:32"

Comment: I revomeved the javascript code towards the end of the  <body> and put that function's code into an echo statement in the central <?php?> block

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {$nome = $_SESSION['username'];}
                        else $nome = "nessun utente connesso";
                        if (!$nome || $nome == "") {$nome = "non definito";}
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            window.alert("nome utente aggiornato"); var nm = '.$nome.';
                            var sc = document.getElementById("spia_connessione").innerHTML;
                            sc = nm;
                        </script>';

Comment: Why would you suggest adding `ob_start();` with no flush or echo of the buffer contents?